# fb:live-stream won't work in Chrome

Tags: facebook, fbml, xfbml

The fb:live-stream tag won't work in Chrome when I add it to my facebook application. It works fine in Firefox.

```
<div class="content">
   <fb:live-stream event_app_id="1234" width="519" height="625"/>
</div>
```

Anyone already had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

works for me? in both.

what does it display instead?

one idea:
your developer has to visit the stream to activate it, i.e. your facebook api_key is assosciated with a number of developers. every new stream only gets created once a developer accesses it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It doesn't display anything instead. And I'm a developer of the application and it doesn't change a thing

Comment: could your fb_init call be happening before the <fb:live-stream /> is loaded? I think I also saw a strange bug, try <fb:live-stream> </fb:live-stream> instead of doing it in one tag. But all of this is guess-work. ;)